# Git clone not working on EC2 for a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

I am running a CI/CD pipeline as a test in Jenkins. The first task in this pipeline it to clone a [repository](https://github.com/subsari/snippets.git)

I am getting an error that says

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProjectPipeline-Dev/docker/apache
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProjectPipeline-Dev@tmp/durable-2f74d056/script.sh: line 9: cd: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProjectPipeline-Dev/docker/apache: No such file or directory
```

This pipeline is set up on an AWS EC2 instance. I installed git on this instance so I dont know why the clone isnt working.

Here is the log for the pipeline:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because when you clone a git hub repo with `git clone https://github.com/subsari/snippets.git` it clones it into a directory snippets, so your `docker/apache` directory is actually inside the `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProjectPipeline-Dev/snippets/`

You need to cd as

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProjectPipeline-Dev/snippets/docker/apache
```

or you can also use the `dir` in your Jenkinsfile sa

```
dir("snippets/docker/apache"){
    sh "pwd"
    sh './script.sh'
}
```